# How to add magento ui image uploader in store/system config?

Tags: magento2, system-config, magento-ui, store-config

I need to insert an image uploader like this.
[image: I need to insert image uploader like this.]

Comment: I did this, but I have two file upload UI components in one form. After generation, a bug occurred. The two of them have the same behavior. I deleted the image of A, and the image of B was also deleted. I uploaded the file of A in B, and also uploaded the same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create system.xml at app/code/Vendor/ImageUploadConfig/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        ...
        <field id="upload_image" translate="label" type="Vendor\ImageUploadConfig\Block\Adminhtml\Image" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
            <label>Select Image</label>
        </field>
        ...
    </system>
</config>
```

Create Image.php file at app/code/Vendor/ImageUploadConfig/Block/Adminhtml/ folder to create block file.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ImageUploadConfig\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    public function __construct(
        Factory $factoryElement,
        CollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        Escaper $escaper,
        $data = [],
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Mime $mime,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct(
            $factoryElement,
            $factoryCollection,
            $escaper,
            $data
        );
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->mime = $mime;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT);
    }
    public function getElementHtml(){
        
        $initData = [
            'config' => [
                'initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath' => 'wysiwyg',
                'previewTmpl' => 'Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/uploader/preview',
                'uploaderConfig' => [
                    'url' => 'pagebuilder/contenttype/image_upload',
                ],
            ]
        ];

        $data = array_replace_recursive($initData, $this->getData());
        $uiComponent = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Media\Image::class);
        $uiComponent->setData($data);
        $uiComponent->prepare();
        $this->setData($uiComponent->getData());

        return '<div id="content_img_id" data-bind="scope:\'upload_image\'">' .
                    '<input type="hidden" name="'.$this->getName().'"data-bind="value: $data.value()[0] ? $data.value()[0][\'url\'] : \'\'" />' .
                    '<!-- ko template: $data.elementTmpl --><!-- /ko -->' .
                    '<script type="text/x-magento-init">'.
                        '{
                            "#content_img_id": {
                                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                                    "components": {
                                        "upload_image": {
                                            "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/image-uploader",
                                            "elementTmpl": "ui/form/element/uploader/image",
                                            "config": '.json_encode($this->getConfig()).',
                                            "value": '.json_encode($this->getValue()).',
                                            "dataScope": "upload_image"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }'.
                    '</script>' .
                '</div>';
    }

    public function getValue(){
        $filePath = parent::getValue();
        $newfilePath = explode('/', $filePath);
        unset($newfilePath[0], $newfilePath[1]);
        $newfilePath = implode('/', $newfilePath);
        $image = [];
        if ($newfilePath && $this->mediaDirectory->isExist($newfilePath)) {
            $stat = $this->mediaDirectory->stat($newfilePath);
            $mime = $this->mime->getMimeType($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($newfilePath));
            $image[0]['name'] = basename($newfilePath);
            $image[0]['url'] = $filePath;
            $image[0]['size'] = isset($stat) ? $stat['size'] : 0;
            $image[0]['type'] = $mime;
        }
        return $image;
    }
    
}
```

After apply this run **php bin/magento c:c**